# Apollo client useQuery is skipping but not re-running the query when the skip flag becomes false?

Tags: reactjs, apollo, apollo-client, react-apollo

So we have 2 different queries we run to grab user permissions and what not. There is a ton of data and it greatly varies how we set permissions. So, the initial `GET_STUFF` grabs a bunch of preliminary data, and `GET_STUFF_ASYNC` needs to wait until the first query is done (hence `skip: loading`).

```
  const { loading, data } = useQuery(GET_STUFF);
  const {
    loading: permissionsLoading,
    data: permissionsData
  } = useQuery(GET_STUFF_ASYNC, { skip: loading });
```

Further down, we have this:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (permissionsLoading || !permissionsData) {
      return;
    }
    doStuff() // set the user's permissions data that come in.
    });
  }, [permissionsData]);
```

The issue is, that in some cases where I control+click to open multiple tabs, if I'm not viewing those tabs while they are fetching data, the useEffect typically returns early and permissionsData never gets updated so that we update a user's permissions.
So, A: should GET_STUFF_ASYNC re-run when loading becomes false, even though it's skipping initially?
B: Is there another way of going about this?
 We want `GET_STUFF` to complete before running `GET_STUFF_ASYNC`. But for whatever odd reason, when I open a tab and don't actually view the newly opened page for awhile, certain things won't get updated.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `useLazyQuery` instead of `useQuery` . useLazyQuery API is similar to useMutation which gives you a function which you can trigger programatically .

```
const { loading, data } = useQuery(GET_STUFF);

const [ getAsyncStuff , {
    loading: permissionsLoading,
    data: permissionsData
  }] = useLazyQuery(GET_STUFF_ASYNC);

useEffect(() => { 
   // when the first query is loaded, then fire this lazy query function
  if(!loading){
     getAsyncStuff()
  }
 }, [loading])
```

**Refer**

[useLazyQuery](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/react/hooks/#uselazyquery)

Comment: Great, I'll look into this. Just curious, in your code, did you mean to write = useLazyQuery(GET_STUFF_ASYNC) instead?

Comment: Ah yes . Thanks for pointing it out . Have updated my answer .

Comment: it seems I'm still having the issue of the permissionsData not updating. The useEffect() which it is used in does not make it through the initial check- perhaps it never comes in at all.

Comment: It does about.. 50% of the time.It's really only reproducible when I open a bunch of tabs and visit those tabs later. Some load in data from the query correctly, others don't. But I'll double check to make sure the query is even firing correctly in those other instance.